# Run code when app is terminated on silent push notification in ios 13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, voip

I am working on messaging application which is a module form our app. Before **IOS 13** major changes in **voip**, we are ok with voip imlementation when app is terminated, but now as everyone knows the major change in voip restrict us for use of voip only for instant messages. So i need help now that how can we **perform a task** when app is **terminated** on silent push notification.

Comment: The user terminating your app is a clear signal. They don't want you to do any work.

Comment: Then how IM(instant messages) apps will work. An app want to save incoming messages in local DB. so what happens when app is killed?

Comment: They get a regular push notification and retrieve the backlog of messages when the app launches. Silent push isn't supposed to be used for high volumes anyway. Apple recommends 2-3 silent pushes per hour. See this document from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silent push notifications are extremely unreliable and should not be used for instant messaging. VoIP pushes must only be used for reporting incoming calls.

What you can do for instant messaging is creating a [Notification Service app extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) and sending regular pushes with the key `"mutable-content":1`. This way, the app extension will run in the background when the user receives a notification, making it possible for you to modify the notification's content and perform some tasks before presenting it to the user - note that your app will not wake up, only the extension. To update your database, you must share the same DB between your app and this extension, by enabling app groups and saving the DB file in the group's directory.